# Show that $\bigcup_{t\in I}U_t\times\{t\}$ could be not open although $I$ is open and $U_t$ is open for each $t\in I$.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

So let be $I$ an open interval of the real line and thus let $U_t$ for each $t\in I$ an open set of a topological space $X$. So I ask to clarify if the set
$$
\bigcup_{t\in I}U_t\times\{t\}
$$
is open or not in the product topology. I am sure that the statement is generally false but unfortunately I did not find any counterexample: in particular I'd really like clarify the statement when $X$ is the euclidean plane $\Bbb R^2$. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: What if you just pick a random $U_t$ for each $t\in I$, play with that a bit. E.g. Pick two different $U$ and $V$ disjoint and let $U_t=U \text{ or } V$ depending on whether $t$ is rational or irrational, say.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So e.g. let be $U_t:=\begin{cases}(0,1)\times(0,1)\,\,\,\text{if}\,\,\,t\in\Bbb Q\\(-1,0)\times(-1,0)\,\,\,\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ right?

Comment: So now how to show that $\bigcup_{t\in I}U_t\times\{t\}$ is not open in $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: assume it contains a basic product open set and derive a contradiction.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So if $\bigcup_{t\in I}U_t\times\{t\}$ was open in the product topology then it would be neighborhood of any its element so that for any $(x,t)\in U_t\times \{t\}$ there must exist an open set $U_x⊆X$ and an open interval $I_t⊆\Bbb R$ such that $$U_x\times I_t\subseteq\bigcup_{t\in I}U_t\times\{t\}$$ but this is impossible because if $t∈\Bbb Q$ and $\mathscr t∈I_t∩\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ then $$(x,t)\in U_t\times\{t\}\wedge(x,\mathscr t)\in U_\mathscr t\times\{\mathscr t\}\Rightarrow x\in U_t\cap U_\mathscr t$$ and this is clearly impossible. So are my argumentations correct?

Comment: Yes, I summarised in an answer.

Comment: Take $U_0 = X$ and $U_t = \emptyset$ for $t > 0$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Oh yeah! I will happy if you will write it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the example by the OP in the comments:
$X=\Bbb R^2$ and $I=(0,42) \subseteq \Bbb R$

$$U_t := \begin{cases} (0,1)^2 & t \in \Bbb Q \cap I\\
                       (-1,0)^2 & t \in I\setminus \Bbb Q \\
         \end{cases}$$

And suppose that $O \times (a,b)$ some non-empty basic open subset of $\bigcup_{t \in I} U_t \times \{t\}$. If $x \in O$ we can find both a rational $q \in (a,b)$ and an irrational $r \in (a,b)$. It follows that $(x,q) \in (0,1)^2 \times \{q\}$ and hence $x \in (0,1)^2$ and also $(x,r) \in (-1,0)^2 \times \{r\}$ and hence $x \in (-1,0)^2$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks very much for your support! You was really helpful, thanks yet.